# Is really QueryString case insensitive?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on a payment platform and, in response to a payment, a simple GET call, with some params in the query string, is made to my listener:

> http://localhost/mytest/listener?TIMECREATED=04.08.2015+12%3A22%3A27&statoattuale=OK&PREVIOUSSTATE=IN&CURRENTSTATE=payment_approved&tipomessaggio=PAYMENT_STATE&**DESCRIZIONE**=CAMBIO+DI+STATO&datacreazione=04.08.2015+12%3A22%3A27&**stabilimento**=xxxxxx&**MerchantNumber**=xxxxxx&**descrizione**=CAMBIO+DI+STATO&OBJECT=PAYMENT&TIMEGENERATED=04.08.2015+12%3A23%3A17&**MERCHANTNUMBER**=xxxxxx&statoprecedente=IN&MERCHANTACCOUNT=xxxxxx&numeroOrdine=myOrderNo&numeroCommerciante=xxxxxx&datagenerazione=04.08.2015+12%3A23%3A17&ORDERNUMBER=myOrderNo&**Stabilimento**=xxxxxx&**mac**=CaWJiRCxbWH%2FsNFMvHUD2A%3D%3D&**MAC**=AnsEvRHkvMwRL%2FgehVtnhA%3D%3D

When I inspect `Request.QueryString` what I get is a mess of the param order and case. Seems like they are reordered with adjusted case for the first occurence. Like this:

> TIMECREATED=04.08.2015
>   12:22:27&statoattuale=OK&PREVIOUSSTATE=IN&CURRENTSTATE=payment_approved&tipomessaggio=PAYMENT_STATE&**DESCRIZIONE**=CAMBIO
>   DI STATO&**DESCRIZIONE**=CAMBIO DI STATO&datacreazione=04.08.2015
>   12:22:27&**stabilimento**=xxxxxx&**stabilimento**=xxxxxx&**MerchantNumber**=xxxxxx&**MerchantNumber**=xxxxxx&OBJECT=PAYMENT&TIMEGENERATED=04.08.2015
>   12:23:17&statoprecedente=IN&MERCHANTACCOUNT=999988801&numeroOrdine=myOrderNo&numeroCommerciante=xxxxxx&datagenerazione=04.08.2015
>   12:23:17&ORDERNUMBER=myOrderNo&**mac**=CaWJiRCxbWH/sNFMvHUD2A==&**mac**=AnsEvRHkvMwRL/gehVtnhA==

To me it looks like a bug, becasue the RFC3986 states:

> When a URI uses components of the generic syntax, the component
>   syntax equivalence rules always apply; namely, that the scheme and
>   host are case-insensitive and therefore should be normalized to
>   lowercase.  For example, the URI  is
>   equivalent to http://www.example.com/.  The other generic syntax
>   components are assumed to be **case-sensitive** unless specifically
>   defined otherwise by the scheme (see Section 6.2.3).

At the moment I solved my problem by manually parsing `Url.Query`, but I still do not think that how behave Request.QueryString is correct.

Can someone shed some light on the matter?

Comment: What exactly is your question/problem? `Request.QueryString` is not case sensitive. You can use `Request.QueryString["test"]` or `Request.QueryString["TEST"]` and both will get the same parameter value

Comment: That's my point. If you try to do `Request.QueryString["mac"]` you will get `CaWJiRCxbWH/sNFMvHUD2A==,AnsEvRHkvMwRL/gehVtnhA==` (both values separated by a comma) also for `Request.QueryString["MAC"]` and `Request.QueryString["mAc"]` you will get the same result. And also, why `Request.QueryString` feel the need to change the order and the case of the params?

Comment: RFC say that params must be considered case sensitive. So why it did not respect that?

Comment: The RFC is fine. .Net's facilities that let you interact with it are an entirely different matter. If you need a strictly case sensitive approach then you need to do what you did.

Comment: In case anyone comes here because they're wondering if `HttpContext.Request.Query["foo"]` is case-insensitive, it relates to the same thing and therefore, yes it also is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the API doesn't provide a way to make the `Request.QueryString` collection case sensitive (or the `Request.Headers` or `Request.Form` collections, for  that matter).

However, with a bit of reverse engineering via reflection, it is not that difficult to do.

```
public class CaseSensitiveQueryStringCollection : System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
{
    public CaseSensitiveQueryStringCollection(string queryString, bool urlencoded, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
        // This makes it case sensitive, the default is StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
        : base(StringComparer.Ordinal)
    {
        if (queryString.StartsWith("?"))
        {
            queryString = queryString.Substring(1);
        }

        this.FillFromString(queryString, urlencoded, encoding);
    }

    internal void FillFromString(string s, bool urlencoded, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
    {
        int num = (s != null) ? s.Length : 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            int startIndex = i;
            int num4 = -1;
            while (i < num)
            {
                char ch = s[i];
                if (ch == '=')
                {
                    if (num4 < 0)
                    {
                        num4 = i;
                    }
                }
                else if (ch == '&')
                {
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
            string str = null;
            string str2 = null;
            if (num4 >= 0)
            {
                str = s.Substring(startIndex, num4 - startIndex);
                str2 = s.Substring(num4 + 1, (i - num4) - 1);
            }
            else
            {
                str2 = s.Substring(startIndex, i - startIndex);
            }
            if (urlencoded)
            {
                base.Add(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(str, encoding), HttpUtility.UrlDecode(str2, encoding));
            }
            else
            {
                base.Add(str, str2);
            }
            if ((i == (num - 1)) && (s[i] == '&'))
            {
                base.Add(null, string.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
var query = new CaseSensitiveQueryStringCollection(
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Query, 
    true, 
    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

When you use a querystring like `?MAC=123&mac=456`, you can see they are kept separate.

Comment: I ended up with something similar, what I would like to understand is why QueryString does not repsect the RFC and we have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Quite simply because Microsoft decided that ease of use trumped strict adherence. If you have ever spent hours trying to track down an issue that occurred only because you had the wrong case in the string (or URL), you know what I mean. But I don't understand why they didn't make it easier to switch on case sensitivity than this - it should have just been a configuration switch. Perhaps this is a cue to create an open source project that provides a complete case-sensitive HttpContext based on HttpContextBase so everyone doesn't have to reinvent the wheel for this.

Comment: That's a nice suggestion. I guess I find my new weekend project :)